# reactjs / Webpack 3 - how to compile scss into a separate css file?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, karma-webpack

**How to convert the .scss to .css files while copying(CopyWebpackPlugin(){}) them to the dist/ folder but I’m not able to figure it out.**

Using copy-webpack-plugin version --- 4.0.1

My package structure is like that, I'm trying to copy my *.scss file to *.css and I need to transform a file inside it.

```
         |-- App 
            |-- dist **//expected result**
              |-- sass
                |-- elements
                    |-- variables1.css
                    |-- variables2.css
                |-- common
                  |-- colours.css
            |--components
                |-- TextArea
                  |-- TextArea.css
                  |-- TextArea.js
                |-- user
                  |-- user.css
                  |-- user.js
```

and so on...

```
            |-- src
                |-- styles
                    |-- main.scss
                |-- sass
                    |-- elements
                        |-- variables1.scss
                        |-- variables2.scss
                    |-- common
                      |-- colours.scss
                |--components
                    |-- TextArea
                      |-- TextArea.scss
                      |-- TextArea.js
                    |-- user
                      |-- user.scss
                      |-- user.js
                |--components2
                    |-- TextArea2
                      |-- TextArea2.scss
                      |-- TextArea2.js
                    |-- user2
                      |-- user2.scss
                      |-- user2.js
                |-- index.js
            |-- app.js
            |-- webpack.config.js
            |-- karma.config.js
            |-- package.json
```

my webpack.config looks like ..

**webpack.config.js**

```
const webpack = require('webpack')
const path = require('path');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

const config = {
  entry : {
    index:'./src/index.js'
  },
  output : {
    filename: '[name].js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    publicPath: '/dist/',
    pathinfo: true
  },
  devtool: 'source-map',
  module: {
    rules: [{
      test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
      loader: 'babel-loader'          
    }, {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract(['css-loader', 'resolve-url-loader', 'sass-loader'])
    }
  },
  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin({
      filename:  (getPath) => {
        return getPath('path of file/ScrollArea.scss').replace('css/js', 'css');
      },
      allChunks: true
    }), **// tried this way too ...but not working**
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([
      {
        from: 'path of file/ScrollArea.scss',
        to: 'path of file/ScrollArea.scss',
        toType: 'file',
        transform: function (content, path) {
            return content.toString('path of file/ScrollArea.css', '/');
        }
      }, **// tried this way too ...but not working**
      {
        from: 'path of file/TextArea.scss',
        to: 'path of file/TextArea.scss'
      },
      {
        from: 'path of file/Hint.scss',
        to: 'path of file/Hint.scss'
      }
    ]),
    new ExtractTextPlugin('/path of file/main.scss', {
       allChunks: true
    })
  ],
  externals: {
    'react/addons': true,
    'react/lib/ExecutionEnvironment': true,
    'react/lib/ReactContext': true
  }
};

module.exports = config;
```

Am I doing something wrong, Please suggest me How can I achieve?

Comment: So if I understand well, your jsx/js still has references to scss files which do not exist in the dist folder as all scss there is distributes as normal css? Right? Really interesting question, maybe something with the extracttext plugin to search/replace all  imports for .scss with *.css. Anyhow will trackt the question for an answer...

Comment: yes,it's right!